# Unable to print validation errors with a for loop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have just started learning HTML and JavaScript.
I am trying to validate an HTML form for empty fields and print the corresponding error messages as output using a for loop.

Below is the jsp page and javascript code.

```js
<script>
  var err = new Array();
var i = 0,
  flag = 0;

function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["RegistrationController"]["firstname"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    err[i++] = "First name cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var a = document.forms["RegistrationController"]["dob"].value;
  if (a == null || a == "") {
    err[i++] = "Date of birth cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var b = document.forms["RegistrationController"]["address_line_1"].value;
  if (b == null || b == "") {
    err[i++] = "Address cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var c = document.forms["RegistrationController"]["city"].value;
  if (c == null || c == "") {
    err[i++] = "city cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var d = document.forms["RegistrationController"]["pincode"].value;
  if (d == null || d == "") {
    err[i++] = "pincode cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var e = document.forms["RegistrationController"]["mobile_no"].value;
  if (e == null || e == "") {
    err[i++] = "mobile no cannot be empty";

    flag = 1;
  }
  var f = document.forms["RegistrationController"]["email"].value;
  if (f == null || f == "") {
    err[i++] = "email cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (flag == 1) {
    var string = "";
    for (j = 0; j < err.length; j++) {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err[i];
      return false;
    }
  }

} </script>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

  <title>Registration</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="error" id="error"></div>
  <h1>Registration Form</h1>
  <div class="ex">
    <form name="RegistrationController" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <table style="with: 50%">
        <tr>
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Last name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Date of Birth</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="dob" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address Line 1</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="address_line_1" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address Line 2</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="address_line_2" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>state</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="state" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>city</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="city" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>pincode</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="pincode" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobile no</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="mobile_no" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>email</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>gender</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" />Male</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" />Female</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="register" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `innerHTML += err[i]+'<br>';` as `innerHTML` will replace `HTML` in every iteration...

Comment: the function is not even defined because you have written the script tag as < script > instead of <script> (spaces after < are not allowed)

Comment: i am getting **undefined** as output @Rayon.

Comment: acutally i have not given space in my eclipse .But space is showing here..no idea why @fdreger

Answer (score 1):

Refer this answer. I have modified your code a bit.

- `<script>` tag should not include spaces after <
- in displaying iterator `i` is refered but you have used `j` in for loop
- I think using getElementById is more efficient

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function validateForm() {
  var err = new Array();
var i = 0;
 var flag = 0;
  var x = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

  if (x == null || x == "") {
    err[i++] = "First name cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var a = document.getElementById("dob").value;
  if (a == null || a == "") {
    err[i++] = "Date of birth cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var b = document.getElementById("address_line_1").value;
  if (b == null || b == "") {
    err[i++] = "Address cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var c = document.getElementById("city").value;
  if (c == null || c == "") {
    err[i++] = "city cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var d = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
  if (d == null || d == "") {
    err[i++] = "pincode cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  var e = document.getElementById("mobile_no").value;
  if (e == null || e == "") {
    err[i++] = "mobile no cannot be empty";

    flag = 1;
  }
  var f = document.getElementById("email").value;
  if (f == null || f == "") {
    err[i++] = "email cannot be empty";
    flag = 1;
  }
  if (flag == 1) {
    var string = "";
    for (j = 0; j < err.length; j++) {
      document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err[j];
      return false;
    }
  }

} </script>


<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

  <title>Registration</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="error"id="error"></div>
  <h1>Registration Form</h1>
  <div class="ex">
    <form>
      <table style="with: 50%">
        <tr>
          <td>First name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" />
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Last name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Date of Birth</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="dob" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address Line 1</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="address_line_1" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Address Line 2</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="address_line_2" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>state</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="state" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>city</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="city" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>pincode</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="pincode" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mobile no</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="mobile_no" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>email</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="email" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>gender</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" id="gender" />Male</td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" id="gender" />Female</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="button" value="register" onclick="validateForm();" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when you use `getElementById` ,  u have to define the inputs id like this `<input type="text" name="lastname id="lastname" />`

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating with variable `j` and using `i`.

```
   document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err[i];
```

use this instead:

```
   document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = err[j];
```

And as suggested by Rayon append instead of rewriting the values:

```
   document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += err[j];
```